# ASP.NET MVC call REST Service from server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

During an action in an API controller (Server side) I have to call a REST service (I have an external REST service that return the user country by IP), wait for the returning results and continue execution... 
What is the best way of doing so?

Comment: you can use HttpClient class and make requests that you need

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find a tutorial using HttpClient [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Example for a Resource GET:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // New code:
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
        }
    }
```